# Project Euler 009 Problems

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

In Project Euler's problem 9, I encounter a problem: infinite loops.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

bool isPythagorean(int a, int b, int c);

int main(){
        int a;
        int aa;
        int b;
        int bb;
        int c;

        for(a = 0; a <= 1000; a++){             /*a loop*/
                aa = a;
                for(b = aa; b <= 1000; b++){     /*b loop*/
                        bb = b;
                        for(c = bb; c <= 1000; c++){
                                if(isPythagorean(a,b,c)){
                                        if(a + b + c == 1000){
                                                std::cout << (a * b) * c;
                                                return 0;
                                        }
                                else
                                        continue;
                                }





                }




        }

        return 1;
}
bool isPythagorean(int a, int b, int c){
        int Pa = (int) pow(a, 2);
        int Pb = (int) pow(b, 2);
        int Pc = (int) pow(c, 2);
        if(a < b && b < c){
                        if(Pa + Pb == Pc)
                                return true;
                        else
                                return false;    
        }

        else
                return false;
}
```

Courtesy of everyone who has helped the idiot writing this, the code has been changed, but the error still stands:

When the code is run, nothing is output to the terminal. Could anyone kindly tell me what is going wrong here?

(*I am such an idiot; My thanks go to everyone that is even looking at this.*)

Thank you, istrandjev for noticing a whole host of bad pieces of code.

Thank you, Blastfurnace for noticing that stupid error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: StackOverflow is about sharing, not getting your answer (actually... helping you in a competition) and then removing the answer from the community.

Comment: So, I shouldn't take it down after?
Thank you SLaks!

Comment: One obvious problem is that you're missing curly braces around the body of the `b loop`. The unusual formatting of your code makes it hard to read and notice such things.

Comment: I don't deserve _only_ one mark down. Why post code with stupid errors? Thank you, Blastfurnace.

I've got it all working now. Again, thank you to everyone who helped with this... Programmers are brilliant people; one day I'll be up there with you Gods.

Comment: Note that your `c loop` isn't needed. At that point you know `a` and `b` and that `a+b+c` must equal 1000. Simply compute `c` and then do your `isPythagorean` test. This should speed up your solution. (There are other changes you can do to reduce the amount of work being done.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get much of the logic you are trying to apply. What is a%1==0&&b%1==0&c%1==0 checking? You can simply write it if(true), you know. Also when is the cycle supposed to end? How is a triplet supposed to be Pythagorean if one of the conditions is a > c and then you want to have a*a + b*b == c*c?

Comment: I was meant to be checking if each one is an integer.
The cycle is meant to end when the answer is found... But, as you asked, I may just limit it to 1000
a > c is silly. Sorry.

Thank you though.